# VS2015 attach to process for specific named iis websites

Tags: visual-studio-2015, attach-to-process

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 I noticed that the vscommands attach to process is no longer available. I found this so very useful, as I could click a button ion the toolbar and a dialog would open containing all the websites I have in the code base. This allowed me to pick and choose at will.

Unfortunately now I have to click on the 'attach to process' option, and then in the dialog highlight all the w3wp entries as theres no way of differentiate between the websites.

I did try ReAttach plugin but this only gives you the standard IIS/APPPOOL... or SYSTEM... and not the website name. Does anyone no of any plugins that allow you to see the website name as configured in IIS?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Debug Attach Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a667daf-be94-4be5-a92a-71732b8dd60a).
I works pretty well as a replacement for vsCommands shortcut.

From the site:

> This extension gives you ability to search for processes and then attach to them. It automatically saves selected processes between Visual Studio restarts. You can easily find apppool specific processes and attach to them. Extension has attach shortcut key, by default it is Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F5. You can attach to multiple processes at once. If you are web developer then you must have it.

Comment: I've tried this one, but I can't see my virtual directories, like VSCommands used to do. Anyone know how to get this working?